# Передача параметров в функциях с переменным числом параметров

Tags: c

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void myPrintF(const char *__format, ...)
{
    va_list arg;
    va_start (arg, __format);
    printf(__format, arg);
    va_end (arg);
}


int main(void)
{
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm* aTm = localtime(&t);
    myPrintF("Close log %04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n",aTm->tm_year+1900, aTm->tm_mon+1, aTm->tm_mday, aTm->tm_hour, aTm->tm_min, aTm->tm_sec);
    printf("Close log %04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n",aTm->tm_year+1900, aTm->tm_mon+1, aTm->tm_mday, aTm->tm_hour, aTm->tm_min, aTm->tm_sec);
    return 0;
}
```

Почему выводит это? Как исправить?

```
Close log 6422164/-10800/1567025724 6422152:1980360769:1904456
Close log 2019/08/28 20:55:24
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почему вы решили, что `printf` можно так вызывать? Специально для таких целей есть

```
vprintf(__format, arg);
```

Answer (score 3):

Вместо этого

```
printf(__format, arg);
```

воспользуйтесь

```
vprintf(__format, arg);
```